# CheckBox(String str) Constructor is undefined

Tags: checkbox, javafx-8

I am trying to make a CheckBox using javafx-8 but the constructor which intialises the label associated with it that is CheckBox(String str) is not defined similarly the setSelected method and setText methods are not defined in the library.
I have updated java to the latest version Java SE 8u131 but the problem is still there.
Here's the code

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class CheckBox extends Application {

Stage window;
Scene scene;
Button button;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    window = primaryStage;
    window.setTitle("JavaFX");

    //Checkboxes
    CheckBox box1 = new CheckBox("apples");
    CheckBox box2 = new CheckBox("Tuna");
    box2.setSelected(true);

    //Button
    button = new Button("Order Now!");
    button.setOnAction(e -> handleOptions(box1, box2));

    //Layout
    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
    layout.getChildren().addAll(box1, box2, button);

    scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();
}

//Handle checkbox options
private void handleOptions(CheckBox box1, CheckBox box2){
    String message = "Users order:\n";

    if(box1.isSelected())
        message += "Bacon\n";

    if(box2.isSelected())
        message += "Tuna\n";

    System.out.println(message);
}
```

}

Here's the Error log

```
CheckBox.java:24: error: constructor CheckBox in class CheckBox cannot be applied to given types;
    CheckBox box1 = new CheckBox("apples");
                    ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
CheckBox.java:25: error: constructor CheckBox in class CheckBox cannot be applied to given types;
    CheckBox box2 = new CheckBox("Tuna");
                    ^
 required: no arguments
 found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
CheckBox.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
    box2.setSelected(true);
        ^
  symbol:   method setSelected(boolean)
  location: variable box2 of type CheckBox
CheckBox.java:35: error: method addAll in interface ObservableList<E> cannot be applied to given types;
    layout.getChildren().addAll(box1, box2, button);
                        ^
  required: Node[]
  found: CheckBox,CheckBox,Button
  reason: varargs mismatch; CheckBox cannot be converted to Node
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface ObservableList
CheckBox.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
    if(box1.isSelected())
           ^
  symbol:   method isSelected()
  location: variable box1 of type CheckBox
CheckBox.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    if(box2.isSelected())
           ^
  symbol:   method isSelected()
  location: variable box2 of type CheckBox
```

I am using eclipse ide but its not problem of that too because i have tried compiling it through ubuntu's shell.
How should i rectify this ?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Your own class is called `CheckBox`, which is a recipe for trouble... Use a different name, or, if you insist on using this as your own class' name, you'll have to use the fully-qualified name `javafx.scene.control.CheckBox checkbox = new javafx.scene.control.CheckBox("...");`.

Answer (score 2):

CheckBox is your class name,so rename your class name and import javafx checkbox

```
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
```

or use fully qualified name like that.

```
javafx.scene.control.CheckBox box1 = new javafx.scene.control.CheckBox("apples");
javafx.scene.control.CheckBox box2 = new javafx.scene.control.CheckBox("Tuna");
```

In handleOptions() method

```
private void handleOptions(javafx.scene.control.CheckBox box1, javafx.scene.control.CheckBox box2) {
```